# TeX Capacity Exceeded. Why?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, stack

I am getting an error message of some capacity being exceeded and I'm not sure why as the new code compiles just fine in overleaf.com but does not compile on my computer when I copy/paste it in.

FYI: I'm making number lines where, say, the top will be in thirds and the bottom will be in fifths.

This compiles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\DNL}[5]   % xscale, yscale, xmax, top denom, bottom denom
{
 \draw (0,0)--(#3,0);  % the main x-axis

 \pgfmathsetmacro{\topdenom}{#3*#4}   % the top denom
 \foreach \x in {0,...,\topdenom}
  \draw (\x/#4,0)--(\x/#4,0.25); 

 \pgfmathsetmacro{\bottomdenom}{#3*#5}  % the bottom denom
 \foreach \x in {0,...,\bottomdenom}
  \draw (\x/#5,0)--(\x/#5,-0.25);
}

\begin{document}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=5, yscale=1.25]

\DNL{5}{1.25}{3}{3}{5}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Yet when I copy the macro into the preamble where I have all my other macros, then copy the code into the body of the document, I get that error message.

I double checked my macros to make sure nothing else is called `\DNL` and nothing else is. Not sure what else to do... My document isn't even all that complex as it is mostly fractions worksheets for kids and teenagers.

What's going on?

Comment: The example compiles. Without a non working example it's difficult to say more.

Comment: Yes, I can understand the problem there.  How might I search for the part(s) of the code in the greater document that is/are causing problems? Are there "standard" causes of this error message?

Comment: Just start from a copy of your document that fails, delete any packages that you can delete while still generating the error and post the smallest example that generates the error.

Comment: You have given absolutely _no_ information that would allow anyone to guess the cause. You haven't even said what limit you hit. All your question says is "error message of some capacity being exceeded " TeX would have reported _exactly_ what capacity you exceeded, and what the current maximum value was, and at what point in the document it hit that limit.

Comment: Please post a MWE that shows the error, and also paste the full error that you're getting.

Comment: FYI: The exact quote of the error:  "Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size = 5000]".

Comment: Hey, thank you to everyone that has posted. I just found the problem, though, and I actually defined `\DNL` in another place that I had completely forgotten about. I'm not sure why I didn't get that error that says something to the effect of `\DNL already defined`, but it's all working out now.

Comment: voted to close as unclear as you've solved it and confirmed the problem is in code not shown.